# Converting .csv file to file.shp using Python gives IndexError?

Tags: pyqgis, convert, csv, pyshp, indexerror

I have a file.csv like the following:

```
37.0925854357,14.3860984446,0.0000079572,0.0000939491,0.0000028935
37.0978554286,14.5199850398,0.0000041594,0.0000821038,0.0000047924
37.1029267200,14.6538928343,0.0000024414,0.0000677266,0.0000050637
37.1077992514,14.7878210195,0.0000094944,0.0000632959,0.0000020797
```

where the first two columns represent longitude and latitude.
The file.csv can be seen as an array of data having dimensions (**n**x**m**), where **n** is the number of rows and **m** the number of columns.In my case **n = 1107** and **m = 367**. How can I convert it to a file.shp without defining all the fields?
To convert this file I used the following commands

```
import shapefile, csv

output_shp = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)
output_shp.autoBalance = 1
counter = 1
with open('path/to/file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        lon= row[0]
        lat= row[1]
        output_shp.point(float(lon),float(lat))
        output_shp.record(lon, lat)
        counter = counter + 1
# save the Shapefile
output_shp.save('path/to/output/file.shp')
```

I got this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shapefile.py",line 986, in record
if self.fields [0] [0] .startswith ("Deletion"): fieldCount - = 1
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I correct the code?

Comment: Have you considered answers to check what's wrong with your code? https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=convert+csv+to+shp+using+pyshp

Comment: @PolyGeo I know that my mistake is in defining the fields.
The .csv file can be seen as a matrix of data having dimensions (nxm), where n is the number of rows and m the number of columns. In my case n = 1107 and m = 367.
I asked this question because I can not define all the fields from 0 to 367.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set your output shapefile field names for example

```
    output_shp.field('lon', 'F')
    output_shp.field('lon', 'F', 10,10)
```

You will see above I specified "10,10". Depending on your version of the shapefile library, it could bring an error by not specifying the length/precision of the float (see https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp/issues/99#issuecomment-325588300 )

You can now also change the below

```
    output_shp.point(float(lon),float(lat)) #From this
    output_shp.point(lon,lat) #to this
```

I think everything else looks ok, but if you still have issues then please post updated error messages.

---

In your comment you mention you have 367 fields and don't want to name individually. Thus, you could just set a loop for this:

```
    for i in range(1,368):
        fname = "field" + str(i)
        output_shp.field(fname)
```

set/Get the value for each field using a similar loop.

Answer (score 0):

I genuinely think that using GDAL/OGR directly is far easier... You may just add an extra line to the top with the header

```
Longitude, Latitude, f1, f2, f3
37.0925854357,14.3860984446,0.0000079572,0.0000939491,0.0000028935
37.0978554286,14.5199850398,0.0000041594,0.0000821038,0.0000047924
37.1029267200,14.6538928343,0.0000024414,0.0000677266,0.0000050637
37.1077992514,14.7878210195,0.0000094944,0.0000632959,0.0000020797
```

Then just use `ogr2ogr`

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" \
        -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Lon* -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Lat* \
        -oo KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS=NO stuff stuff.csv
```

If you don't want to use the shell, you can use `gdal.VectorTranslate` to create the shapefile directly from within Pyton.

Comment: I don't think it can be ok because my file.csv has 367 columns and to use your solution I have to define 367 fields.

Comment: OK, I didn't think of this, but adding more fields is no issue here (I just made sure it worked for your case). However, the shapefile format [has a limit of 255 fields](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/appendices/geoprocessing-considerations-for-shapefile-output.htm#GUID-A10ADA3B-0988-4AB1-9EBA-AD704F77B4A2) so I don't see how you can get away with that with a Shapefile...